# calculate the difference between 2 series in tooltip for highstock

Tags: javascript, tooltip, highcharts, formatter

I need some help to find a solution to display the difference between the series in the tooltip.

[Here](http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150223/dcysxgrd.jpg) <- is a simple screenshot with my problem:

how can i solve this for Hamburg to Matif and Niederrhein to Matif?

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // ------ Testchart Kassakurse Raps in Hamburg für 2014  ------ //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $(function() {
        var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            legend: {
                enabled: false   
            },
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'basis-tool_test',
                plotBackgroundImage: 'images/background_large.png'
            },
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    printButton: {
                        text: 'Chart ausdrucken',
                        onclick: function () {
                            this.print();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
            },
            title : {
                text : 'Raps - Kassakurse im Jahr 2014',
                style : { "textDecoration": "bold", "fontSize": "20px", "fontFamily": "Tahoma, arial, sans-serif" }
            },
            tooltip: {
                xDateFormat: '%d. %B %Y',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true,
                valueDecimals: 2,
                borderColor: '#000',
                valueSuffix: ' €'
            }
        });

        // Matif Daten
        $.getJSON('scripts/charts/data_arrays/testchart_matifraps_data.js', function(data){
            chart.addSeries({
                id: 'id_matif',
                name: 'Matif Raps',
                data: data,
                color: '#F7A35C'
            }, true);
        });
        // Hamburg Daten
        $.getJSON('scripts/charts/data_arrays/testchart_hamburgfrontmonat_data.js', function(data){
            chart.addSeries({
                id: 'id_hhfm',
                name: 'Hamburg Frontmonat',
                data: data,
                color: '#7CB5EC',
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    /* pointFormat:'<span style="color:{series.color}">● </span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/><b>Basis: </b><br>' */
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.point.y + 'BÄÄÄÄM' ;
            }
                },
                myData: 'firstPoint',
                myOtherData: 'Other first data'
            }, true);
        });
        $.getJSON('scripts/charts/data_arrays/testchart_hamburgfrontmonatplus1_data.js', function(data){
            chart.addSeries({
                id: 'id_hhfm1',
                name: 'Hamburg Frontmonat +1',
                data: data,
                color: '#7CB5EC',
                visible: false
            }, true);
        });
        $.getJSON('scripts/charts/data_arrays/testchart_hamburgfrontmonatplus2_data.js', function(data){
            chart.addSeries({
                id: 'id_hhfm2',
                name: 'Hamburg Frontmonat +2',
                data: data,
                color: '#7CB5EC',
                visible: false
            }, true);
        });

        // Niederrhein Daten
        $.getJSON('scripts/charts/data_arrays/testchart_niederrheinfrontmonat_data.js', function(data){
            chart.addSeries({
                id: 'id_nrfm',
                name: 'Niederrhein Frontmonat',
                data: data,
                color: '#434348'
            }, true);
        });
        $.getJSON('scripts/charts/data_arrays/testchart_niederrheinfrontmonatplus1_data.js', function(data){
            chart.addSeries({
                id: 'id_nrfm1',
                name: 'Niederrhein Frontmonat +1',
                data: data,
                color: '#434348',
                visible: false
            }, true);
        });
        $.getJSON('scripts/charts/data_arrays/testchart_niederrheinfrontmonatplus2_data.js', function(data){
            chart.addSeries({
                id: 'id_nrfm2',
                name: 'Niederrhein Frontmonat +2',
                data: data,
                color: '#434348',
                visible: false
            }, true);
        });

        /* Legend */

        // Buttons
        $('#button_matif').click(function() {
            var chart = $('#basis-tool_test').highcharts();         
            series = chart.get('id_matif');

            if(series.visible) {
                series.hide();
            } else {
                series.show();
            }
        });

        $('#button_hamburg').click(function() {
            var chart = $('#basis-tool_test').highcharts();
            var selVal = $("#list").val();

            if(selVal == "a") {
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm');
                if(series.visible) {
                    series.hide();
                } else {
                    series.show();
                }
            }
            if(selVal == "b") {
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm1');
                if(series.visible) {
                    series.hide();
                } else {
                    series.show();
                }
            }
            if(selVal == "c") {
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm2');
                if(series.visible) {
                    series.hide();
                } else {
                    series.show();
                }
            }
        });

        $('#button_niederrhein').click(function() {
            var chart = $('#basis-tool_test').highcharts();
            var selVal = $("#list2").val();

            if(selVal == "d") {
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm');
                if(series.visible) {
                    series.hide();
                } else {
                    series.show();
                }
            }
            if(selVal == "e") {
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm1');
                if(series.visible) {
                    series.hide();
                } else {
                    series.show();
                }
            }
            if(selVal == "f") {
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm2');
                if(series.visible) {
                    series.hide();
                } else {
                    series.show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Selects
        $("#list").on('change', function(){
            var chart = $('#basis-tool_test').highcharts();
            var selVal = $("#list").val();

            if(selVal == "a" || selVal == '') {
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm');
                series.show();
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm1');
                series.hide();
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm2');
                series.hide();
            }
            else if(selVal == "b") {
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm');
                series.hide();
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm1');
                series.show();
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm2');
                series.hide();
            }
            else if(selVal == "c") {
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm');
                series.hide();
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm1');
                series.hide();
                series = chart.get('id_hhfm2');
                series.show();
            }
        });

        $("#list2").on('change', function(){
            var chart = $('#basis-tool_test').highcharts();
            var selVal = $("#list2").val();

            if(selVal == "d" || selVal == '') {
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm');
                series.show();
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm1');
                series.hide();
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm2');
                series.hide();
            }
            else if(selVal == "e") {
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm');
                series.hide();
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm1');
                series.show();
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm2');
                series.hide();
            }
            else if(selVal == "f") {
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm');
                series.hide();
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm1');
                series.hide();
                series = chart.get('id_nrfm2');
                series.show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tooltip.formatter` - you have there access to the points (`this.points[0]`, `this.points[1]` etc.). Just calculate different between y-values.

Note: `tooltip.formatter` is available only on the highest level of options, like in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bwefs1ak/

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<br/>Value: ' + this.y;
            });

            s+= '<br>Diff: ' + ( this.points[0].y - this.points[1].y );

            return s;
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for ur fast answer! When I add the tooltip formatter I got no results and no errors :/

Comment: Live demo please? It's hard to debug from .. well, nothing ;) Anyway, make sure you have merged `tooltip.formatter` with your actual `tooltip` options.

Comment: i will create a fiddle, moment please :)

Comment: so, here is my completed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bwefs1ak/2/ please take a look to the tooltip now. I added a point format for 'Hamburg Frontmonat' only. There should be the difference behind "Basis: " ('Hamburg Frontmonat' - 'Matif'). Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: That's great, but as I said - you need to use `tooltip.formatter`, not `tooltip.pointFormat` ;) And not on the series level, but in chart options.

Comment: ahh, in chart options it works. Is there no chance on series level? And it is possible to display "Diff" just under Hamburg?

Comment: Okay, I found an solution with if clauses :) Thank u for ur time! ;) But maybe u have a better idea..

Comment: Nope, you can't do that on series level. And you can use `pointFormat` because it prevents all math calcs (just to be on the same page). Well, if=else statement should work. ;)

Comment: Can any one see my question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588901/want-to-take-difference-between-single-series-data-and-show-them-on-chart-in-hig/39589875#39589875

Comment: @PawełFus, how would you do this for the x-axis, within a series? I have a line chart with two series (A and B), time periods on the x-axis, a score on the y-axis. I'd like to show in the tooltip "Difference period 1 vs. period 2 for series A: -5", calculated using `this.point.x` and `previous.point.x` (I know `previous` doesn't work).

Comment: I don't quite understand. When `tooltip.shared = true`, then you have access to `this.points` which is an array of all points with the same x-value. If you want to compare hovered point with different point, then you need to find this second point. Something like `this.point.series.points[index_of_your_point]` vs `this.point`.