# HighCharts arithmetic operations using array and display results in tooltip

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I'm drawing a chart data using Highcharts with no problem so far. What I'm trying to do is to use ***pointFormatter*** function to do some calculation and add that calculation value to **tooltip** which I did successfully like this:

```
// unit is string
        someFunction(unit, unitPrice moneyType) {
            tooltip: {
                        shared: true,
                        useHTML: true,
                        pointFormatter: function() { 
                            return this.series.name + ' : <b>' + this.y + '</b> ' + unit + '<br/>' +
                            localize("em_consumption_comparison_report_price") + ' : <b>' + (this.y * unitPrice).toFixed(2) + '</b> ' + moneyType + '<br/><br/>'; 
                          } 
    }
```

Output works just fine as seen in below pic

[image]

**unit** and **moneyType** was a string value and above code works. But the problem is I figure those variables *should be array*. So I try to workaround the issue and tried this : (by the way in this case unit -> kWh, moneyUnit ->TL)

```
// unit is ARRAY
      tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    pointFormatter: function() { 
                        for (var i = 0; i < unit.length; i++) {
                            return this.series.name + ' : <b>' + this.y + '</b> ' + unit[i] + '<br/>' +
                            localize("em_consumption_comparison_report_price") + ' : <b>' + (this.y * unitPrice).toFixed(2) + '</b> ' + moneyType[i] + '<br/><br/>';
                        }

                      },
    }
```

But that didn't work as seen below picture. 
[image]

So how can I loop through *unit* array in that case? Any tips?

Comment: Any errors in console? Your return in loop - it is the problem. First make the result string for point in your for loop, than return

Comment: @Constantine not any errors in the consol and I don't quite get what you mean as solution

Comment: hmm...so could you write the example of tooltip result you want to get

Comment: @Constantine the same result with the first picture. Output will be the same, but I want to be able to use it with array keys

Comment: `unit.lenght` should be `unit.length`, ?!?

Comment: @MartinSchneider oh I fixed and updated the code block it but still nothing on tooltip

Comment: @FreshPro For what reason do you need for loop which returns in first iteration? May be you should use point index `this.points[0].index` instead of `var i`

Comment: @Constantine Actually I draw two different series in my code. After some database operations, I calculate 2 constant values (1 for the first serie [purple color] and 1 for the second [grey color]) which I refer as unit. 

So I'm trying to use this constants to multiply with point.y for each series.

unit = ["0.40", "0.17"] so to be able to do (point.y * 0,40) I need to iterate

Comment: @FreshPro Well, now i understand u, i suppose. [i think this will help to work with two series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698554/calculate-the-difference-between-2-series-in-tooltip-for-highstock) OR  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944699/can-i-use-two-different-formatters-for-highchart-tooltips)

Comment: @Constantine Let me try to be more specific. y-axis holds consumptions. unitPrice changes for each series and I calculate this unitPrice in php and pass it to JS. In order to show consumption price in tooltip, I need to multiply consumption and unitPrice. That's why I need this

Comment: @FreshPro So just try to differentiate unitPrice by series name and this will help you to create tooltips for each series(with diff. unitPrice). i hope...

Comment: @Constantine all content is dynamic and series name doesnt have to be unique. I guess I have to think harder

Comment: @FreshPro Anyway you need to find a way how to link series with exact unitPrice. It depends on your task and realisation...Captain obvious))